# Adding "First Page" and Last Page" buttons to Crystal Report Viewer ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I am using Crytal Report Viewer to show some reports. In it Navigation buttons for Next and Previous page exist but not for First and Last page. I have to add two buttons in the tool bar of crystal report viewer for this purpose.

[image: Location where I want to place the buttons in Crystal Report Viewer]

I have used property HasPageNavigationButtons="True" but this opens up a menu as in image below. Which is not acceptable to my client. He wants it in the form of buttons only.

[image: When HasPageNavigationButtons= "True" is used]

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.